# $a,b,n,d\in \mathbb N$. $a,b,d$ are different numbers from the interval $(n^2;n^2+n)$. Prove that it can't be true that $d|ab$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$a,b,n,d\in \mathbb N$. $a,b,d$ are different  numbers from the interval $(n^2;n^2+n)$. Prove that it can't be true that $d\mid ab$.

This is an interesting problem and I don't know how to start, so I'd like to get some help from someone. Thanks.

Comment: let d = n^2 + x, a = n^2 + y, b = n^2 + z with 1 < x, y, z < n

Comment: You probably meant $1 \le x,y,z < n$.

Comment: yes. and reduce it to a quadratic equation. try it.

Comment: I hear you.This could well be a combinatorial number theory problem that requires advanced number theory background since the word "random" is used here.

Comment: @MatikKen I removed "random" because an absolute statement ("can't be true") is made. I assume "arbitrary" was meant.

Comment: Matik Ken, can you show us the way you've solved this? It seems like you have a different solution from benh's.

Comment: I think his way is right and I will head in that direction too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $d=n^2+x,a=n^2+y,b=n^2+z$ with pairwise distinct $1\leq x,y,z<n$.

Suppose $d\mid ab$. Then
$$0\equiv(n^2+y)(n^2+z)\equiv(y-x)(z-x) \mod n^2+x.$$
But $0\neq |(y-x)(z-x)|<n^2<n^2+x$, a contradiction to $(n^2+x) \mid (y-x)(z-x)$.

Comment: As $x,y,z$ are pairwise distinct, $y-x \neq 0$ and $z-x\neq 0$.  So $(y-x)(z-x)\neq 0$. The second part follows from -n<y-x<n and -n<z-x<n. The third part is equivalent to 0<x.

Comment: Note that $a \neq b$ is not a necessary condition.

Comment: nice proof @benh. it's easier to spot a line of argument than to boil it down to essentials and express it concisely and clearly.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ \ $ If $\,\rm\ A_i \equiv a_i\pmod d\ $ then $\rm\ d\mid A_1 A_2\iff d\mid a_1 a_2,\, $ which fails if $\rm\ 0 < |a_i| < \sqrt{d}.\ $

Thus we have a simple **indivisibility test:** for "small"  $\rm\,a_i \equiv A_i,\,$  verify that $\rm\,0 < |a_i| < \sqrt d. $

For example,  $\rm\ 30\nmid \color{#c00}{25}\cdot \color{#0a0}{34}\ $ by $\ 0 < \color{#c00}5,\color{#0a0}4 < \sqrt{30}.\, $  Applying this test quickly solves your problem.

**Remark** $ $  This is a simple example of the general principle that conversion of divisibility problems into the *equational* language of modular arithmetic often yields great simplifications, since it enables us to reuse our well-honed intuition about integer arithmetic.

Comment: I don't quite follow this. Should it perhaps be $0 < |a'| < \sqrt d$ etc.?

Comment: @TonyK Yes, that's what I was hinting toward. I hoped that (and the rest) would be easy enough to infer. But perhaps the hint was too concise (reason for the downvote?). I've given more details to avoid any further downvotes. But I fear that by doing so, this spoils the opportunity for the OP to have the best possible learning experience by *discovering* as much as they can on their own (vs. having the complete answer served on a silver platter).

Comment: I'm sure the downvote was just because of showing that $0 < a_1 < \sqrt{d}$ instead of $0 < |a_1| < \sqrt{d}$.

Comment: @mathh That inequality was not *shown*. Rather it is a *hypothesis* in the hinted theorem. The theorem is correct with or without the abs-values in the inequalities. The abs-value form yields a slightly more general theorem (but at the cost of possible obfuscation of the key idea). The abs-value form is the more convenient one to apply to the problem at hand. But I thought that this slight generalization would be fairly obvious to any solver once they tried to apply it in the exercise, and that they might likely learn something by *discovering* it on their own.

Comment: Note to readers: the above comments refer to an earlier version of my answer (which has since been reorganized a bit).